# How can I edit my question that was closed as opinion based?

Tags: discussion, support

I asked the question [Mnemonic for the planets in Indian English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/542411/mnemonic-for-the-planets-in-indian-english) about back in 2020. The question has been closed as opinion-based after less than 2 years. However, I need to ask something about this "elegant mother" and Indians. So, how can  I edit my question?

Comment: I'm not sure you can rescue it.English isn't algebra.   There likely is no rationale for why IndE speakers use X while BrE/AmE speakers use Y beyond "a series of accidents of history.  To hazard a guess, at the time IndE branched off, proper, from BrE, the BrE phrase (at the time) might have been "elegant", but I believe that's a close to a definitive answer (aka my guess) as you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Reframe as a [phrase-origin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/phrase-origin) question

I don't know what type of answer you were expecting, but the answer you got (and accepted) explained the origin of that particular wording. Tracing the origin of a phrase is answered by facts (citations) and reveals as much as can be known about why things happened.